# How can I get an S3 asset's remote path minus the bucket name from within my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, assets

My plugin takes as an argument the id of an asset. So I'm starting from here:

```
   $entry = craft()->elements->getElementById($entry_id);
```

Assuming my asset has the url http://mybucket.mycompany.com/uploads/pdfs/myfile.pdf, how can I return just 'uploads/pdfs/myfile.pdf' from within my plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use the `replace` filter to chop it off...

> https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#replace

Even if you didn't know the bucket name exactly, `replace` supports regex.